# stripe_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. error: invalid source release: 17

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am facing this issue while running my flutter project on VS code, after multiple attepmts still stuck here.
Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.  
Even i have updated the java version by doing this but sitll facing issues.
updated this to 8 to 11 but still stuck here

```
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

When run the flutter project i am facing issues regarding invalid source release 17.

Answer (score 7):

The version of java used by flutter is by default the one embbed in Android Studio (if you have installed) - then JAVA_HOME, and etc.. [check this for more info](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide#notes)

Looks like some step from a gradle script of flutter_stripe relies on java 17.

In my case **I solved it by installing the latest version of android studio**. (then *flutter clean* and voilá!)

`flutter doctor -v` [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWypG.png) after updating it (before, I was using an old version of A.S. with java11 bundled`

Comment: removing flutter_stripe solved my problem thanks.

Comment: Moving forward, more and more flutter plugins are using java 17, so there's no choice but to update Android Studio or any dev environment.

Answer (score 5):

I face this error in Codemagic and this solution solve my problem

In the Workflow Editor under the Environment variables section by defining an env var JAVA_HOME and setting its value to

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64

For mac m1 use this

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home

This fixed my problem.

Just adding a visual context to the answer:
[image]

Comment: I've been banging my head for a few days now, your solution totally saved me!!